# Silencing output of `normalmixEM` from R package `mixtools`

Tags: r

How do I keep `normalmixEM` from printing the number of iterations it required? I am using it in a call inside a bootstrap and the resulting dynamic report in RMarkdown becomes a beast as it prints out the required number of iterations for each bootstrap resample fit, as per the 3-line sample below:

'## number of iterations= 23

'## number of iterations= 16

'## number of iterations= 17

This behaviour seems to be induced by line 128 in the code for function `normalmixEM`, reading `cat("number of iterations=", iter, "\n")`, and I don't seem to be able to silence it.

`normalmixEM` includes an argument `verb` but that is already `FALSE` by default. Tryed RMardown options `message=FALSE,warning=FALSE` but that does not work either. One solution, which essentially silences the entire chunck, is to use `silent=TRUE`, but it would be useful to be able to silence just the output from `normalmixEM`.